# Would i be able to update 12.04 LTS to 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

After installing  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , would i be able to update my system to 13.04 without losing my data? And how i will do it? Can Anyone Tell me?

Comment: I say this every time: always keep two backups of your data before doing anything system-wide.

Comment: I think you can't upgrade directly from 12.04 to 13.04. First upgrade to 12.10 then 13.04 but before that back up your data's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the update manager there will be an option to upgrade to the next verion of Ubuntu.  <del>You might have to go via 12.10 if you are unlucky.</del>

However, only two update paths are supported:

- to the immediate next version
- from one LTS to the next

Therefore, the only direct updates available from 12.04 LTS are 12.10 and 14.04 LTS. You will need to upgrade to 12.10 first and from there to 13.04.

I generally found though that upgrading would introduce subtle but irritating bugs into the system.  So I would recommend just backing up your home folder (an any others containing data you want to keep), making a note of programs/applications you have installed, and performing a clean install.

It is not that much more effort (takes 20-40 mins) and is likely to provide a smoother running system.

Good Luck!

Also see: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but first you will have to upgrade to 12.10

Recently I have upgraded my OS from 12.04 to 12.10 & then after 12.10 to 13.04.

But it's always recommended to keep backup of your data before going for any version upgrade, so better keep it.